# Lead and lagging in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

We know that in an AC circuit, if there is a capacitance current is leading by π/2, so does it mean that when voltage across capacitor is maximum, current through the circuit is 0. And why does this leading our lagging come anyways?

(Aside from the mathematical proof, is there a intuitive way to understand?)

Comment: Do you understand how a capacitor and/or an inductor work, with respect to current and voltage?

Comment: What do you mean wrt current or voltage, I know that capacitor works as due to charge on the plates there is potential difference, so an E field is generated, and inductor acts as a reverse battery if current is increasing to resist the flux increase, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitor's voltage is proportional to the charge it stores, and we can't instantaneously add to/remove from the capacitor a large chunk of charge. Charge is gradually added/removed as current flows through the capacitor. In this sense, capacitors "resist" change in charge, and thus voltage.

Since a capacitor resists voltage variations, if you apply a sinusoidal current waveform, the voltage doesn't follow it exactly in phase but lags behind. When current is zero, the capacitor still has charge and non-zero (let's say positive) voltage. Only when the current goes negative does the capacitor start losing its charge and the voltage start decreasing.